# jplayer support to rtmp videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

Im using **Jplayer** plugin, will it support **rtmp videos?**.I have the code below and it **works** **fine** with the videos in the **local machine**

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        m4v: "${urlvideo}",
                        ogv: "${urlvideo}",
                        webmv: "${urlvideo}"
                    }).jPlayer("play"); 
                },
                swfPath: "/etc/designs/myproject/clientlibs/img",
               solution: toplayHtml ? "html" : "flash", 
              preload:"auto",
              loop:true,
                supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
                size: {
                    width: "${videoWidth}",
                    height: "${videoHeight}",
                    cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
                }
            });
        });
```

**if** jplayer **supports** rtmp videos, do I need any **code change** in the above section like explicitly specifying **rtmp keyword** in the above code.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: It does. Flash version is used for RTMP

Comment: Thanks closure,i need to use this jplayer even in ipad,ipod etc where html5 only is used.So, how we can use jplayer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able just to add the supplied formats according to documentation on jPlayer site. This should work, I haven't tried it.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        m4v: "${urlvideo}",
                        ogv: "${urlvideo}",
                        webmv: "${urlvideo}",
                        rtmpa: "${urlvideo}",
                        rtmpv: "${urlvideo}"
                    }).jPlayer("play"); 
                },
                swfPath: "/etc/designs/myproject/clientlibs/img",
               solution: toplayHtml ? "html" : "flash", 
              preload:"auto",
              loop:true,
                supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v, rtmpa, rtmpv",
                size: {
                    width: "${videoWidth}",
                    height: "${videoHeight}",
                    cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
                }
            });
        });
```

Source: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-supplied

Comment: Thanks for the information Henrik, i need to use this jplayer even in ipad,ipod etc where html5 only is used.So, how we can use jplayer there.

Comment: Sadly you cannot use RTMP as a supplied format for iPhone, iPad etc because iOS doesn't support flash. jPlayer uses flash for RTMP support. You can read more about it here  "The HTML solution does not support RTMP." http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-media-encoding

Comment: ok Henrik,to play in iphone,ipad etc, the only alternative is not to go with rtmp right,thanks Henrik